# Tag grouping by time in the Tags view

Tags: feature-request, tags

Similar to how you can group users by time range in the Users view, please allow the grouping of tags by time in the Tags view. It would look like this:

[image]

Clicking on one of the time ranges would change the sorting and numbers associated with the tags. While it may not seem as interesting here at Meta Stack Exchange, this would be very interesting on other exchanges, especially smaller ones, as it would allow a stronger insight towards tag trends as well as hot tags.

Comment: The information you're looking for can probably retrieved from SEDE, but I agree having it there ^ would make sense as well.